# How to view own permissions in Trac?

Tags: permissions, profile, trac

I'm a user on a publicly available Trac setup of some project. I've been using the XMLRPC interface now for quite some months but today I got a message in my UI that I need XMLRPC permissions.

I'm unsure if this is an error on my end or the permissions have been revoked. I remember I could see the permissions I had at least on the web-frontend of Trac but I don't remember where this was located.

Does anybody know where it is normally located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only visible in the "Permissions" admin panel if you have `PERMISSION_GRANT` or `PERMISSION_REVOKE`. There may be a plugin that does what you want, although a quick search on [trac-hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) doesn't yield anything interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that looks like the location I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can see permissions under `admin/general/perm` but you might need TRAC_ADMIN and/or PERMISSION_ADMIN.